# Историческая ретроспектива — корректно ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Является ли тавтологическим сочетание "историческая ретроспектива"? Можно ли называть тавтологическими не однокоренные сочетания, а сочетания, в которых слова дублируют друг друга по смыслу?

Answer (score 2):

Ретроспектива не всегда связана с историческим контекстом или большим временным охватом прошлого. Можно сослаться этим словом на критический обзор решений какого-нибудь плодовитого губернатора за прошедший год, что "историей" трудно назвать. Это тоже будет "взгляд в прошлое" (таково упрощённое определение ретроспективы), пусть и недавнее. Поэтому прилагательное "историческая" в вашем примере вполне может служить уточняющим определением. То же с "исторической перспективой": это отсылка к *большим промежуткам времени* в будущем.